# Are Klingons obligate carnivores?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "A Matter of Honor" Commander Riker participates in a Federation-Klingon officer exchange program.  The evening before his transfer he gorges himself on Klingon delicacies, presumably to prepare his digestive tract for what's to come.  Everything he eats--- heart of targ, pippius claw, gagh, etc. seems to have come from the living flesh of some animal.  Onboard the Klingon vessel *Pagh* no one seems to eat anything but meat.

All this suggests the question: Are Klingons obligate carnivores?  That is, do they require nutrients found only in animal flesh and therefore must eat meat to survive?

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Prune_juice

Comment: Apparently not, Michael Dorn is a [vegan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dorn#Personal_life).

Comment: The two paragraphs seem to ask different questions. In the first it seems you want to know whether their diet consists exclusively of meat, but that's not the question you ask in the second. As some would say: Elaborate.

Comment: As a side note, startrek.com ran a "Ask a Klingon" column a few years ago. The Klingon in question was attached to the Klingon embassy on Earth. While he didn't think much of human food at first, he grew a great fondness for pork, which he wanted to bring to Qo'noS.

Comment: @Junuxx There is no question in the first paragraph, rather it establishes a preference for animal protein among the warrior class.  I'm asking if this is a fundamental need of Klingons as a group, rather than an aesthetic choice, or a lifestyle, or a cultural preference.

Comment: @Kyle: I never said there was. But thanks for the additional details.

Comment: Klingon dishes do include vegetables; [Zilm'kach](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zilm%27kach) + [Gladst](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gladst), for example.

Comment: From memory alpha Zilm'kach was a Klingon fruit which looked like a small apricot. Its pit was removed before consumption.

In 2370, Julian Bashir and Melora Pazlar ordered zilm'kach with their racht. (DS9: "Melora")

Comment: In the Klingon Art of War- the 'narrator' talks about a baker he frequented and jInjoq bread from- don't know if that counts as canon but if it does I'd say they eat some plant matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that Klingons are **not** obligate carnivores.  I reached this conclusion by first observing that Klingons and humans are in fact the same species.  From the [Wikipedia article on species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species):

> In the study of sexually reproducing organisms, where genetic material is shared through the process of reproduction, the ability of two organisms to interbreed and produce fertile offspring of both sexes is generally accepted as a simple indicator that the organisms share enough genes to be considered members of the same species. Thus a "species" is a group of interbreeding organisms.

In the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Children of Time" we see the product of several generations of human-Klingon interbreeding with hybrids of both sexes present. According to the definition above, Klingons and humans despite morphological differences are "a group of interbreeding organisms" and thus are a single species.

Since humans aren't obligate carnivores, then neither are Klingons.  If some Klingons have dietary preferences or restrictions due to excessive inbreeding or environmental pressures, then the traits are simple variations within the species rather than innate traits.

Comment: Ha. By that rate 90% of the races in the alpha quadrant, if not the galaxy, are of the same species.

Comment: @Xantec Well, maybe.  Spock and most of the other hybrids might have been mules.  One-shot deals, unable to reproduce.  But "Children of Time" removed all doubt with regard to Klingons and humans.

Comment: @KyleJones Infertile offspring [aren't the only possibility](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2007/03/070314-hybrids.html) for interspecies breeding, even just on Earth...

Comment: We do know that Human-Okampa offspring are able to reproduce as well from *[Before and After](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Before_and_After_(episode))*. Also, the occasional female mule has [produced offspring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule#Fertility) when bred to a pure-breed horse or donkey.

Comment: It's always been my assumption that interspecies reproduction often involved a lot more medical assistance than a regular conception.

Comment: It is true that *one* definition of species incorporates reproductive isolation, and *one* aspect  of reproduction isolation can be reproductive incompatibility. However, this does not imply that two organisms are as genetically similar as two humans! Dogs and coyotes are inter-fertile, as are dogs and jackals, frequently producing fertile hybrids. However, these canids are generally considered genetically dissimilar enough to be different species.Cattle and bison can produce fertile hybrids, as can the African wildcat and the domestic cat.

Comment: It plants and bacteria, of course, cross-breeding between species (i.e. genetically very dissimilar organisms) is much more common. Here reproductive isolation is accomplished by geographic factors more often than genetic. I certainly find it improbable that an obligate carnivore species and an omnivore species could interbreed, but it is not as impossible as you make it out to be. The Klingons could well have suffered a bottleneck effect, where only a few progenitors of their species survived some disaster.

Comment: Example: MTHFR polymorphism Ala222Val can cause a need for increased folate intake. If the human population were whittled down to mainly individuals with this mutation, in an environment where folate-rich foods were common, it is quite possible that a future human population would need very high folate intake, but still be capable of interbreeding with non-polymorphous humans.

Comment: Well, the question is, why cannot one "subspecies" be an obligate carnivore when another "subspecies" is not.  Humans and Klingons are certainly far more different in other ways than any two subspecies on earth currently.

Comment: Everything until your last paragraph is _technically_ correct, albeit inconsistent with the way the term "species" is used in Star Trek. But regardless of their ability to interbreed, Klingons and Humans obviously come from different evolutionary lineages and have different anatomies and physiologies. For example, Klingons are established to have two livers and three lungs. Therefore, we have a strong counterexample to the principle that that what is medically true for Humans must also be true for Klingons.

Comment: I'm strongly against down voting except in specific reasons so I won't do it.  But this is one of the most wrong answers I've ever read and it is baffling that it it green checked too.

Comment: @lucasbachmann It was the best answer at the time I accepted it, lo, 8 years ago.  Post a better answer, win the check mark.

Comment: "There is a technical definition of 'species' by which humans and Klingons are the same species. And we generally think of the word 'species' as meaning that there aren't any significant physical differences. Therefore, humans and Klingons do not have any significant physical differences." That's just silly.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to say, they do eat a lot of meat (at least the warrior class does), though this is not definitive.

On [this site](http://www.omegacron.com/klingons/anatomy.htm) I found reference to the fact that Klingons cannot absorb nutrients as easily as humans can, which means more live food (though not necessarily meat) in their diets rather than preserved foods.

This would explain a strong *preference* for (live) meat as opposed to non-meat foods or preserved meat, but probably not obligate carnivores.

Comment: I find that dubious.  A major reason to cook food is to make it chemically easier to digest.  Another to kill parasites.   I'd suspect klingons treat everything like raw sushi because they prefer the taste and their stomach acid and enzymes can destroy everything.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in things that only appeared in novels, *A Burning House* describes a popular Vulcan restaurant in First City on Qo'nos.  (The Vulcans, as you probably know, are vegetarians).  According to [the Memory Beta page](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_Cuisine), it "catered largely to Vulcanoids in the Klingon Empire's capital city, but also had a share of Klingon customers".

This doesn't really answer whether Klingons can survive with *no* meat, but it does show that they can eat meals that aren't meat, and at least some of them enjoy it.

Comment: I don't really think this addresses the question. Humans are capable of eating grass but that's not the same as saying that they could survive on a cow's diet