# Does gagh provide complete nutrition?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, food

Klingons sure love their gagh.  It seems like they're eating the creepy-crawlies every time we see Klingon food.  Even if there are other Klingon foods, it raises the question: **Does gagh have all of the nutrients that an adult Klingon needs?**  Can one live on gagh alone, without supplementation from other foods?

Obviously, you'll need a warrior's drink to wash them down, like blood wine or prune juice.  You can disregard that for the purposes of this question.

[image: Klingon gagh]

Related: [Are Klingons obligate carnivores?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27091/102339)

Comment: This seems like you're just asking for speculation.  There is no official answer.

Comment: Or they're asking because they don't know if there is an official answer and would like to find out.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it has no nutritional value at all and Klingons just eat it as a 'battle' to finish the huge plateful and keep it down...

Comment: My research for the question revealed at least two books on Klingon food.  Because I don't own either book, I don't know if they would help to answer the question, nor do I know how "official" these books are.  But they are plausible sources for an answer to the question.

Comment: ...part of this complete breakfast?

Comment: @DavidJohnston I don't disagree with you, but I think you'll find that a majority of questions on this site are just speculation.

Comment: @DrSheldon IIRC Star Trek canon only encompasses what is on screen, the TV episodes and the movies (except Threshold)

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain there is no canon answer, with that being said it is doubtful that a single food could contain everything a being needs.

While gagh is pretty much ubiquitous when we see Klingon food this is most likely because gagh is a staple food like rice or corn to humans and we see or hear about a good number of other Klingon food.